# Textbox.text is not getting filled, C#

Tags: c#

i'm building a win App and in that, i'm having a textBox which is get filled dynamically, and i have a checkBox, when `checkBox.Checked=true` all the message boxes in my app will get pop'd
(not all at a time, just confirmation msg's whereever i hv coded it, one by one).

my problem is when `checkBox` is checked, my `TextBox.Text` is getting filled its data but when that `checkBox` is unchecked, `TextBox.text` is not getting filled with data, wierd thing is when i tried to debug it, `TextBox.Text` is showing the text, but on gui `TextBox.Text` is not filled, now where`s data ?

```
public void Recharge()
{
  txtTransactionMsgDelegate(Tm) // this is delegate function which fills the text
                               //textbox.text=tm;   i tried this one too,but no use

}
if (Program.AutoManual == "Auto")
{
   if (chkShowMsg.Checked)
   {
        if (returnRows < 1)
            MessageBox.Show(Program.StatusMessage + " But Local Db Failed, NOTEDOWN IN NOTEBOOK");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(Program.StatusMessage + " And Local Db update SuccessFul, RUN UPDATE RECHARGE LATER");
    }
}
```

Delegate Function:

```
// m using this delegate b'coz my above function i.e Recharge() is under BackGroundWorker Thread i.e BackGroundWorker_DoWork() event;
private void txtTransactionMsgDelegate(string Text)
{
   if (txtTransactionMsg.InvokeRequired)
   {
      txtTransactionMsg.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { txtTransactionMsgDelegate(Text); }));
   }
   else
     txtTransactionMsg.Text = Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the textbox is updated on the GUI you should call `txtTransactionMsg.Refresh();`